# How to write and read Cyrillic properly from file?

Tags: c++, cyrillic

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string rus = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    string lat = "abvgděëžzijklmnoprstufhcčšŝŭeûâABVGDĚËŽZIJKLMNOPRSTUFHCČŠŜŬEÛÂ";
    ifstream gdata("data.txt");
    if(!gdata){
        gdata.open("data.txt");
    }
    string temp;
    while(gdata){gdata >> temp;}
    gdata.close();
    ofstream sdata("data.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++){
        int index = rus.find(temp[i]);
        if(index == -1){sdata << temp[i];}
            else{sdata << lat[index];}
    }
    sdata.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to read Russian Cyrillic from a file. Then, program would find the index of each character in the string **rus**, and if it finds the character, then it finds the corresponding letter within **lat** string. This letter would then be written to the file. 
Unfortunately, when I type something into the file and then run the program, I get weird output such as  @>A8 with random squares (not visible here for some reason). How can I make my program read the Cyrillic properly? 
I have already looked at over 10 questions here about similar subjects, but considering I'm very much a beginner in C++, nevermind encoding, I didn't understand the answers in the slightest, mainly as no example was provided that I could understand.

Also, even if most characters are latin and there is just one Cyrillic in the text, the entire text becomes malformed into random letters like  @>A8

Comment: You will need to know something about encoding. And probably a bit more than just Unicode, because you appear to be using a strange encoding. Many encodings are fairly pure 8-bit extensions of ASCII, so if you confuse the encoding you get a _different_ set of non-ASCII characters. But "@>A8" is all ASCII. Corrupting the entire text is a strong indication that you're dealing with a _stateful_ encoding, where some bytes mean "switch to different character set".

Comment: @MSalters While your input is greatly appreciated, I'm afraid it does not explicitly aid me in producing any solution.

Comment: That was what I feared, which is why I made my response a comment instead of an answer.